# Transition of list based on a criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

[image]

In **Columns A:B** you can see the `months` and the `Calender Weeks (CW)` which belong to each month.

In **Columns D:J** I want to transit/collapse the `CWs` based on the `month` which the user enters in **Cell D1**. For example if the user enters `January` all `CWs` of January should appear in **Row 2** in the **same order** as in the table in **Column A:B**.

Is there something like a combination of the `OFFSET` and `VLOOKUP` function to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you [Pivot](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w5DHU8SwYJ0)?

Comment: with a filter on month. remove totals from totals & filters tab on pivot table options and uncheck field captions and filter dropdowns from the display tab. of pivot table options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this close enough using a pivot and unchecking 3 options in the pivot table options.
[image]